# Riemann vs Riemann-Stieltjes Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

What are the advantages of Riemann-Stieltjes integral over the Riemann Integral?
(Can you please explain using terms which could be understood by a non-mathematician).

Comment: $\emptyset$, Haha, I love the answer

Comment: Actually, I wish someone would answer, I'm interested in knowing after I first saw the definition/chapter on the subject in one of my books.

Answer (score 2):

The Riemann Stieltjes integral is generalization of Riemann integral.
In that kind integration we integrate one function say $f$ with respect another
say $g$ then we write $\int f(x)d(g(x))$. It has many applications in for example probability theory. Mathematical expectation of a random variable is a Riemann stieltjes integral.